# Upload file in selenium without input[@type='file'] element

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a small program written in C# which is to upload some pictures through a form.
It worked a long time ago, but recently the form has changed and the HTML code is totally different now.
It worked because the old form had an input tag of type "file".

My old code:

```
IWebElement picture = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='file']"));
picture.SendKeys(path);
```

But the new form doesn't has input tag.
Only a label element contains an input tag but this element is located outside the div and it is hidden:

```
<label>
<input accept="image/*,image/heif,image/heic" class="csac3eeddac" multiple="" type="file">
</label>
<div>....</div>
```

In styles tab there is this code (so it is hidden):

```
.csac3eeddac {
display: none;}
```

I modified my code, but it doesn't work:

```
IWebElement picture = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[@type='file']"));
picture.SendKeys(path);
```

Can you help me in this case?

Comment: *"But the new form doesn't [have] input tag"*... but there is an `input[@type='file']` there.. where is the `<form>` you keep referencing to? or do you mean document in some senses?

Comment: clarify what you mean by *"it worked a long time ago"* - how is it not working now? are you seeing exceptions? outside of automation testing, does this page and form work following these changes?

Comment: The old HTML code contians the input tag inside a div.
The new HTML code contains the input tag in a hidden <label> outside the div.
Maybe I misunderstand your question.

Comment: I got access to the new site with the new HTML code.
So I need to rewrite my old program to work with the new site before it will be publicated.

Comment: what selenium exception are you getting when running an old code?